# copy n number of files from one folder to another folder

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have  a folder of n number of files. I need to move n/2(or)n/3 files from that folder to any other folder. How to set the value of n so that it will move exact those number of files?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have tried?

Comment: @KasiyA I disagree, copying a fixed number is different from copying a relative number. Though terdon's answer is suited to that question.

Comment: @KasiyA No, as my answer shows. By using sed to divide the input into half, third, etc., I could do it without knowing how many files are originally present.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
k=1; find source/ -type f | while read file; do
     [[ k++ -le 20 ]] && cp "$file" target/ 
done
```

That will find all files in the current directory and copy the first 20 it finds to `target/`. The trick is the `$k` variable which is initialized to `1`. Then, the `[[ k++ -le 20 ]] && cp` means "If $k plus one is less than or equal to 20, run the cp command".

The above will break if your file names contain spaces or newlines or other strangeness. If that can be an issue, use this safer version instead:

```
k=1; find source/ -type f -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do 
        [[ k++ -le 20 ]] && cp "$file" target/ 
    done
```

If you don't need to descend into subdirectories, just do

```
k=1; for file in *; do [[ k++ -le 20 ]] && cp "$file" target/ ; done
```

Finally, to calculate `n` on the fly, you can do (note that this will also count subdirectories)

```
files=( * ); ## save all files in the current directory in an array
n=$(echo "${#files[@]} / 3 " | bc) ## get the value of n/3
for file in "${files[@]:1:$n}"; do cp "$file" bar/; done
```

The solution above should work with arbitrary file names, even those including newlines.

Comment: Thanks for giving me something to improve on! :-) You realize, of course, that the last solution will sweep up subdirectories along with plain files, and it will skip dot (`.`) files. … … … Why do you use `bc` when you need the result truncated to an integer? (I.e., why not just use `$(( ${#files[@]} / 3 ))`?)

Comment: @G-Man yes, skipping dotfiles was intentional, they normally want to be skipped (though the 1st solution will copy them too). As for subdirectories, yes indeed, I thought I had added a disclaimer for that but I wrote this just before going out and was in a hurry. Thanks for pointing it out. I used `bc` out of habit to tell you the truth. No good reason for it :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `find`, `sed` and `xargs`:

```
find /path/to/dir -print0 | sed -nz '1~2p' | xargs -0 cp --target-dir=/some/dir
```

`sed -n '1~2p'` prints every alternate line, thus reducing the count to half. To make it a third, use `1~3p`. The `-print0`, `-z` and `-0` options indicate that we're using the `\0` (NULL) character to delimit things.

References:

- [how to reduce number of lines by half with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633952/how-to-reduce-number-of-lines-by-half-with-sed)
- [Could sed or awk use NUL character as record separator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170119/could-sed-or-awk-use-nul-character-as-record-separator)

Answer (score 2):

To do a fraction (e.g., ⅓) without knowing the count in advance,

```
k=0; for file in *
do
    if [ $((k++ % 3)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        mv "$file" target/
    fi
done
```

This will grab every third file,
by keeping a running counter (`k`) and acting on each file for which `k` is a multiple of 3. 
Since I started the counter at 0, this will round up;
e.g., if you have ten or eleven files (or twelve), it will move four of them.

If there are subdirectories (or exotic files, like FIFOs) in the current directory,
and you want to move ⅓ of the *plain files*, leaving the others alone, change the above to

```
k=0; for file in *
do
    if [ -f "$file" ]  &&  [ $((k++ % 3)) -eq 0 ]
    then
        mv "$file" target/
    fi
done
```

If you want to descend into subdirectories, say

```
shopt -s globstar
```

and use `**` instead of `*`. 
If you want to include names that begin with a dot (`.`), you must also `shopt -s dotglob`.

The above solution should work with arbitrary file names, even those including newlines.